# Large Woocommerce Site (83,000 items), What Can I Do?

Tags: php, plugins, mysql, nginx, varnish

So I have a really large woocommerce site (partsboss.co) that has around 83,000 items.  It's on VPS hosting with digitalocean, and things were running super fast until around 50,000 items.  Now the site is just draaaaaaaaaging.

It's set up on Ubuntu with nginx, APC and Varnish caching.  I'm not really sure where the bottle neck is or how to fix it, but as far as I can tell it's basically taking forever to query the mysql database and return results.

So my question is, do I need to just optimize mysql more (if so, how? Not really a mysql expert) or do I need to split the database with something like Hyperdb? Again, if that's the case, I read the readme for Hyperdb and it wasn't too explicit... if you know of any good tutorials, throw them my way :)  Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? What do you see in the server logs? You will probably need to enable MySQL Slow Query log for the debugging.

Comment: have you done any of this http://www.brainstormcreative.co.uk/website-design/wordpress-woocommerce-speed-how-to-make-them-faster/ im at 26k products en route to 200k+ and having same issues

Comment: I have noticed that since WP3.6 the new admin-ajax.php has been hammering the database. Due to the new heartbeat 'feature.' Profile your plugins and see which ones are eating db time.

Answer (score 0):

Did either of you solve your issues with Woocommerce being slow?

After some profiling, I determined it was PHP being slow, not SQL.

```
Total query time: 0.05915s for 89 queries.
Page generated in 22.00653s (99.73% PHP, 0.27% MySQL)
```

With that info, nothing you change in the front end is going to solve anything.